# Why is Pitest throwing a NoSuchMethodError?

Tags: java, maven, pitest

So I recently upgraded one of my repos to Java 11 and updated the versions of some of the other dependencies. After going through several of the dependencies and resolving all of the errors, I finally got the application to pass all unit and integration tests and it was running normally again. However, when I push the project it also automatically performs mutation tests through Pitest.

This is done in a completely clean environment: a docker container is spun up with the necessary Java and Maven versions (Java 11 and Maven 3.6.3).

The mutation tests fail to compile now, and the following stack trace is given:

```
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19    [WARNING] Error injecting: org.pitest.maven.PitMojo
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19    com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19    
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19    1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.pitest.functional.FCollection.mapTo(java.lang.Iterable, java.util.function.Function, java.util.Collection)'
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19      at org.pitest.maven.PitMojo.<init>(Unknown Source)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19      while locating org.pitest.maven.PitMojo
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19    
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19    1 error
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalProvisionException.toProvisionException (InternalProvisionException.java:226)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1053)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:520)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.pitest.functional.FCollection.mapTo(java.lang.Iterable, java.util.function.Function, java.util.Collection)'
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.pitest.maven.DependencyFilter.<init> (DependencyFilter.java:42)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.pitest.maven.AbstractPitMojo.<init> (AbstractPitMojo.java:365)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.pitest.maven.PitMojo.<init> (PitMojo.java:14)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0 (Native Method)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:490)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$ReflectiveProxy.newInstance (DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:126)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision (ConstructorInjector.java:114)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000 (ConstructorInjector.java:32)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call (ConstructorInjector.java:98)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct (ConstructorInjector.java:93)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:306)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:520)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
18-Aug-2021 15:57:19        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

This is only a part of the stack trace, but I believe it is the relevant part, I can grab more of the stack trace if necessary/requested.

I have not been able to find much information about this issue. Any similar topics/posts I have found on StackOverflow/GitHub just suggest to either perform a `mvn clean` or to upgrade to a newer version (the most common I've noticed mentioned is Pitest 1.4.3). However, as I said the mutation tests (in fact all of the tests) are run in a completely new and clean environment and we upgraded Pitest from 1.1.11 to 1.5.2.

In fact, I was originally going to leave Pitest at version 1.1.11, but was getting an `IllegalArgumentException` instead, and assumed it was just because it needed to be upgraded.

Why is this exception being thrown? Is Pitest missing a dependency that I need to add? Where can I find more information on errors like this, and what debugging might I be able to do to find the cause and form a solution?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the pom, and also confirm if it does/doesn't work if you run it on your own machine without docker etc.

Comment: Doubt it's relevent, but why pitest 1.5.2 and not 1.6.9?

Comment: @henry Using 1.5.2 because that is the most recent version my company has available. I will post a scrubbed version of the pom later today. It seems to be able to run locally, so this may be an issue with the docker container. One difference is that my local machine has Java 11.0.10 and the docker container is using 11.0.12, but I find it unlikely that that is the issue.

Comment: The error log also says `Unable to load the mojo 'mutationCoverage' in the plugin 'org.pitest:pitest-maven:1.5.2' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: 'void org.pitest.functional.FCollection.mapTo(java.lang.Iterable, java.util.function.Function, java.util.Collection)'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out our remote environment was running the tests a slightly different way and was using a plugin for pitest that was not explicitly defined in our POM. The plugin was [Alex Victoor's pitest-cucumber-plugin](https://github.com/alexvictoor/pitest-cucumber-plugin) which includes a compatibility matrix that I was able to use to resolve the issue.